# Sale price fall back to higher sale price on sale finish

Tags: sale-price

I am trying to achieve a very different scenario for my few items.

**What I need**

Have product with 3 prices (org price, sale price, and higher sale price) with sale price expiry date.

**How it should work**

When sale price expires then it should fall back to higher sale price.

**Example**

Let's say product has price of $100 and sale price is $60 and expiry date is tomorrow.

When sale expires tomorrow, by default magento rule it will fall back to `rrp` but I want it to fall back to `another user defined sale price (i.e. higher sale price: $70)`.
I can create a new `price attribute` to have new price field for each item.

**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, looks like I have to answer it myself. After few days of struggle I came to use observer to achieve this.

So decided to run a daily cron to check if there are any `special price to date` for any product within my category and then do the business logic.

> Cron runs everyday at the midnight.

**My observer.php**

```
public function scheduledChangePrice()
    {
        $category_id = 132;
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
                    ->getProductCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
                    //->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
                     ; //sets the order by price
        $i = 0;
        //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(3338);//(3389);
        foreach($products as $product){
            $i++;
            if($product->getSpecialToDate() && ($product->getSpecialToDate() . ' 11:59:59 PM') <= $this->getCurrentDateTime()){
                $product
                        ->setSpecialPrice($product->getSpecialPrice() + 5) //add $5 to special price so it falls to higher sale price
                        ->setSpecialToDate(null) //remove special to date so that cron doesn't run again
                        ->save();
            }
        }
    }

public function getCurrentDateTime($_storeId = null, $_format = 'm/d/y H:i:s') {
        if (is_null($_storeId)) {
            $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        }
        $storeDatetime = new DateTime();
        $storeDatetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/timezone', $_storeId)));  

        return $storeDatetime->format($_format);
    }
```

Hope this will help someone.